# Spring Cloud Kubernetes not loading Secrets on Spring Boot 3.1.3 with Spring Cloud 2022.0.4

Tags: spring, kubernetes, cloud, kubernetes-secrets

We are upgrading a Spring application from Spring Boot 2.7.12 with Spring Cloud 2021.0.7 to new Boot version 3.1.3 and Cloud version 2022.0.4.

We use Spring Cloud Kubernetes to read secrets from the kubernetes deployment: In our old setup this worked fine, but with the new versions it no longer works.

To re-create this I went to the Spring Initialzr and created a bare bones application with the new versions, added the dependency:

```
<dependency>

  <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>

  <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-kubernetes-client-config</artifactId>

</dependency>
```

added a Rest controller that returns the result of a @Value resolved property, and recreated the non-working setup. Simply downgrading to the older versions makes it work.

The test setup is a little tricky: you have to have kubectl configured, and pass some commandline parameters and environment variables (KUBERNETES_SERVICE_HOST and KUBERNETES_SERVICE_PORT) to mimic that the program is running inside kubernetes.

I run on a Windows PC, so I created a file c:\temp\secrets\cell001\password.key and the content is WrongPassword, and pass that location as spring.cloud.kubernetes.secrets.paths  (under real kubernetes we mount the secrets as a volume into the pod)

Add simple rest controller:

```
@org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController
@RequestMapping("/") 
public class RestController {

    @Value("${password.key:dummyDefault}")
    private String prop;

    @GetMapping("/getProp") 
    public String getProp() { 
        return "@Value:" + prop; 
    } 
}
```

Here is a list of params I pass and keep the same between versions.

```
-Dlogging.level.org.springframework=TRACE   
-Dserver.port=8081   
-Dspring.cloud.kubernetes.reload.enabled=false   
-Dspring.cloud.config.enabled=true   
-Dspring.cloud.kubernetes.client.serviceAccountNamespacePath=mynamespace  
-Dspring.cloud.kubernetes.client.namespace=mynamespace   
-Dspring.cloud.kubernetes.secrets.namespace=mynamespace   
-Dspring.cloud.kubernetes.enabled=true   
-Dspring.cloud.kubernetes.configmap.enabled=false   
-Dspring.main.cloud-platform=kubernetes   
-Dspring.cloud.kubernetes.secrets.enableApi=true   
-Dspring.cloud.kubernetes.config.enableApi=false   
-Dspring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true   
-Dspring.cloud.kubernetes.secrets.paths=c:/temp/secrets   
-Dspring.cloud.kubernetes.secrets.enabled=true  
-Dspring.cloud.kubernetes.secrets.retry.enabled=false  
-Dspring.cloud.kubernetes.secrets.fail-fast=true  
-Dspring.profiles.active=kubernetes   
-Dkubernetes.auth.tryKubeConfig=false   
-Dmanagement.health.jms.enabled=false   
-Dspring.cloud.config.uri=http://localhost:8888/
```

Hitting http://localhost:8081/getProp with Boot version 3.1.3 and Cloud version 2022.0.4 gives: **@Value:WrongPassword**

Hitting http://localhost:8081/getProp with Boot version 2.7.12 and Cloud version 2021.0.7 gives: **@Value:dummyDefault**

Is this a bug? Do I need to pass additional parameters?

Comment: This did change with spring v3. At least one difference I notice is `spring.config.import=kubernetes` is now required.